# Extending (stoppable) threading subclass with threaded methods

Tags: python, multithreading, class, video, python-multithreading

I'm trying to create a subclass of threading.Thread whose methods are threaded. I'm using it for video, but I suspect that a working example will be generally useful for folks.

I realized here that I never instantiated a thread and never called the `start()` method, but I don't know where to call it from or how. I also want to save the thread handle so I can stop it if I receive a `stop()` signal.

```
import threading

class VideoThread(threading.Thread):
    """Thread class with a stop() method. The thread itself checks
    regularly for the stopped() condition."""

    def __init__(self, playlist=None):
        super(VideoThread, self).__init__()
        self._stop = threading.Event()
        self._player_pgid_list = []
        if playlist:
            self.start_sequence(playlist)

    def stop(self):
        self._stop.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop.isSet()

    def start_sequence(self, playlist):
        if not isinstance(playlist, list):
            raise ValueError("Expecting a list")
        for video in playlist:
            if not self.stopped():
                self.__start_video__(video)

    def __start_video__(self, video):
        if not isinstance(video, dict):
            raise ValueError("Expecting a dictionary of video data")
        # start the video
        # store the video pgid so we can kill it if we have to
        # tight wait loop to check for stopped condition
        # kill all video(s) if necessary using the stored pgids
```

The class works as far as it goes, but of course, none of the methods are actually threaded.

`start_sequence()` is public so I can start a threaded sequence of videos like this:

```
video = VideoThread()
video.start_sequence([films[1], films[3], films[2]])
```

Or when I instantiate the class like this:

```
video = VideoThread([films[1], films[3], films[2]])
```

Later, if I need to stop it, I can:

```
video.stop()
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You should rename the `start_sequence` method to `run` and delete the `playlist` parameter (use `self.playlist` instead). Also, delete those two last lines in `__init__` method. I mean:

```
class VideoThread(threading.Thread):


    def __init__(self, playlist=None):
        super().__init__()
        self._stop = threading.Event()
        self._player_pgid_list = []
        self.playlist = playlist

    def run(self):
        if not isinstance(self.playlist, list):
            raise ValueError("Expecting a list")
        for video in self.playlist:
            if not self.stopped():
                self.__start_video__(video)

    ...
```

Then, to use your class just do:

```
playlist = VideoThread(films)
playlist.start()
```

And you can stop it using:

```
playlist.stop()
```

Note that when you call `.start`, it invokes the `run` method in a separate thread of control, check the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) for more information.

Comment: Using this method, can I chain ``start()``, as in ``VideoThread(films).start()``?

Comment: Yes, you can, but if you do so you are loosing the reference to the thread and that means you won't be able to stop it later. Personally, is something I wouldn't do.